# Populate a map with a default value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a map of 48 default key value pairs.
This code works fine:

```
var m = new Map();

for(var i=1; i <= 48 ; i++) {
  m.set(i,'0')
}
```

But, I want to know if this can be done without using for loop.

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: nothing just wanted to know whether this can be done without for loop or not.

Comment: Using a for loop is the best way to achieve what you need

Comment: As far as I know almost all solutions will use some kind of inner loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an array to the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor:

```
const map = new Map([...Array(48)].map((_, i) => [i + 1, '0']));
```

If your first key can be `0` instead of `1`, this would be a cleaner solution:

```
const map = new Map(Array(48).fill('0').entries());
```

Comment: `i` should be `i + 1` though.